# How to test React component with mount method of enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to use the `mount` method of the **enzyme** library to render a custom component but it fails with the error

```
Invariant Violation: Tester.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

together with some annoying stack traces.

Here is the code snippet

```
import React from 'react'
import {shallow, mount, render} from 'enzyme'


describe('Dashboard', () => {
    let testComp;
    beforeEach(()=>{
        testComp = mount(  <UserDashboard />  )
    });

    it('should render self without breaking.', () => {
        expect(testComp).not.toBe(null)
    })

})
```

But I noticed that the problem is not with the `UserDashboard` component because I still get the same error when I replace it with a simple `div` element.

```
testComp = mount(  <div />  )
```

The `shallow` and `render` methods work pretty well but the `mount` method is being really stubborn.

Please I'm new to testing react components and any help on why this is happening will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you correctly [configured enzyme adapter](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/) ?

Comment: Thanks @nubinub, that was the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually a compatibility issue between my react version ( **react v15.6.2** ) and the enzyme adapter I was using ( **enzyme-adapter-react-16** ). It was normally supposed to be **enzyme-adapter-react-15**.

For anyone having this same problem, make sure to visit [this link](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/) on how to configure and use enzyme with your version of react. Thanks to @nubinub for the link